# Allowing non-Super Admin users to reset a user's password in the CP without knowing the old one

Tags: members, password

In EE2, you have to be a Super Admin to change a user's password without knowing their old password in the CP. This is very annoying when you setup up 'Client Admin' member groups as they expect to be able to do such a task for unlocked member groups.

In EE1, there was an add-on called NSM Member Password Security that allowed you to specify member groups that could reset the password without knowing the old one (something that should be part of the standard member permissions in EE, IMO).

But I can't see any such add-ons for EE2. Does anyone have a workaround for this (without giving them Super Admin access)? Or how do you deal with 'Client Admin' member groups that have permission to add/delete member accounts, but can't reset someone's password for them without knowing the old one? Use the forgot password form instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Use the forgot password form instead?

Exactly. Without building custom code to do this (which is quite doable), this is the way to go - and I suggest using [FreeMember](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freemember) and its [Forgot Password](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/wiki/Forgot-Password-Tag) form on the front-end, so users can use it directly. That way your Client Admins don't have to be bothered.

Comment: I get the client admins to use the Forgot password form too. Much easier.